# Jupyter Notebook internal server error

Tags: anaconda, jupyter

I just installed Anaconda and Jupyter Notebook on OSX El Capitan for a data science course on udacity. I am able to launch the notebook in a web browser just fine, but when I click the conda tab (or try to look at my conda packages via the kernel tab in the notebook) I get a message saying "Internal Server Error while trying to retrieve installed packages". In the console the error messages look like this

`[E 17:46:45.657 NotebookApp] Unhandled error in API request
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/jryandx/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/notebook/base/handlers.py", line 503, in wrapper
        result = yield gen.maybe_future(method(self, *args, **kwargs))
      File "/Users/jryandx/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nb_conda/handlers.py", line 62, in get
        self.finish(json.dumps(self.env_manager.env_packages(env)))
      File "/Users/jryandx/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nb_conda/envmanager.py", line 124, in env_packages
        "packages": [pkg_info(package) for package in data]
      File "/Users/jryandx/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nb_conda/envmanager.py", line 124, in <listcomp>
        "packages": [pkg_info(package) for package in data]
      File "/Users/jryandx/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nb_conda/envmanager.py", line 16, in pkg_info
        name, version, build = s.rsplit('-', 2)
    AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'rsplit'
[E 17:46:45.658 NotebookApp] {
      "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
      "Cookie": "_xsrf=2|b81d482d|babef5398d3f91ba9f50d8af2710ce57|1485475524; username-localhost-8888=\"2|1:0|10:1485477133|23:username-localhost-8888|44:MmYxMzY5YTU3M2Q1NDMwM2FlMTg3MzI3NzNkNjI2MjY=|820c4e0cb74c40724977f6035ca0f9028dce07ad780ddc8c9b92548b016e3e4d\"",
      "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.8",
      "Host": "localhost:8888",
      "Connection": "keep-alive",
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 Safari/537.36",
      "Accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, sdch, br",
      "Referer": "http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Untitled.ipynb"
    }`

I dont really have a clue what the problem is. I've searched the web but can't find anything that seems relevant to my specific issue.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to conda 4.3.8 / python 3.6 helps:
conda tab is gone in Jupyter, but instead you have conda-prompt or Anaconda Navigator